# select value from a different select tag

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have two select tag, one french and one english. I want the selected options to change based on the opposite select tag. So if I choose a french word the english equivalent automatically change and vice versa. I'm looking for a pure javascript function.

I've tried multiple different things, but nothing worked.

Here's my html code.

```
<select id="french" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="bonjour">bonjour</option>
  <option value="monde">monde</option>
</select>

<select id="english" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="hello">hello</option>
  <option value="world">world</option>
</select>
```

Comment: _"I've tried multiple different things, but nothing worked."_ Please demonstrate that so we don't replicate your attempts

Answer (score 0):

considering that the order of the matching elements in the selects is correct (option 1 on select french matches option 1 in select english ...), than that fiddle below will work for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/sufo9zxk/

```html
<select id="french" onchange="myFunction(this)">
  <option value="bonjour">bonjour</option>
  <option value="monde">monde</option>
</select>

<select id="english" onchange="myFunction(this)">
  <option value="hello">hello</option>
  <option value="world">world</option>
</select>
```

```js
function myFunction(changedSelect) {

  var otherSelect = document.getElementById(
    changedSelect.id === 'french' ? 'english' : 'french'
  );

    for (var i = 0; i < changedSelect.children.length; i++) {
    var op = changedSelect.children.item(i);

    if (op.selected) {
        otherSelect.children.item(i).selected = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's a good way, but it actcually can't work for me. I have synonyme and more words in french. So it have to be base on the value I was trying with data-* attributes, but it didn't work.